# Mutating redux states between dispatches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I am using React and Redux and trying to dispatch an action from a component but am getting the following error:

> AJAX CALL Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path `dashboard.categories.0.onClick`. This may cause incorrect behavior. (http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)

You can assume the following:

```
menu = [
  {title: "video", onClick: false},
  {title: "gif", onClick: false},
  {title: "website", onClick: false}
];

title = 'video';
```

Here is the component function being used:

```
itemCheck() {
  const {menu, title, actions} = this.props;
  actions.updateCategoryClick(title, [...menu]);
}
```

Redux Action:

```
export function updateCategoryClickSuccess(categories) {
  return {type: actionTypes.UPDATE_CATEGORY_CLICK_SUCCESS, categories};
}

export function updateCategoryClick(category, categories) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(beginAjaxCall());
    return Utils.updateMenuClick(category, categories)
      .then(categories => {dispatch(updateCategoryClickSuccess(categories));})
      .catch(error => {dispatch(ajaxCallError(error));});
  };
}
```

And the utility function being used:

```
export function updateMenuClick(item, menu) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const index = menu.findIndex((object => object.title === item));
    menu[index].onClick = !menu[index].onClick;
    resolve(menu);
  });
}
```

Question:
Why am I being told that a state mutation is happening between dispatches if in fact what I am sending is not the original state (in this case `menu`), but am instead sending it a new copy of the state (in this case `[...menu]`)? And how do I fix this? Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[...menu]` creates a shallow copy, so `this.props.menu[index]` and `[...menu][index]` are still referencing the same object.

Try replacing `menu[index].onClick = !menu[index].onClick` with:

```
menu[index] = { ...menu[index], onClick: !menu[index].onClick }
```

Might be better to do this logic in the reducer though.

Also, returning a promise in your `updateMenuClick` is a bit pointless since it's not async.

Comment: Async means when at least two events are happening at the same time right? Thus, promises ensure that for asynchronous events, when multiple things happen at the same time, each individual item does not get returned until all actions are complete and no longer pending right? (Just trying to teach myself and figure this stuff out). If so then I think I would actually need promises as I might have child components calling this action at the same time.

Comment: You create a promise to wait for an async action in `updateMenuClick`, but there's none in it. Wrapping it in a promise doesn't affect other async events happening outside of the function. This is a complex topic, read up more on async and event loop in JS.

Comment: Constructing a new promise is just a syntactic sugar to replace callbacks (eg. in `setTimeout`), it does not have any practical effects, so avoid it until you fully understand it. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and google for similar topics if those articles are not sufficient.